# Почему вектор не доступен в дебаге

Tags: c++, qt

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Почему содержимое вектора недоступно в дебаге? Вывод вектора корректный.[image: недоступен вектор]

Comment: Подозреваю что понятие "значение" для вектора не имеет смысла.

Comment: вектор - это обертка над обычным массивом, т.е. над куском памяти. Сам по себе вектор не имеет "значения", чтобы отобразить его в дебаге. Чтобы получить доступ именно к содержимому вектора надо написать gi.data() или обращаться по номеру элемента gi[0] - отобразит нулевой элемент в дебаге

Comment: Скорее всего с++ хорошо оптимизировал код и выбросил вектор как ненужное - там все равно используется один элемент.

Comment: ваш код оптимизирован компилятором  на равнозначный:  cout << 8;

Comment: Это был пример для простоты. Если сделать так (см. рисунок), то тоже самое. Дома на ноуте все работает без проблем - содержимое вектора отображется в дебаге.

Comment: Иногда такое бывает. И помогает переключение различных опций для отладчика, а также подключение путей для отладчика. Но это все очень тяжело.